# Bash : Match substrings in string and extract the key value pairs

Tags: bash

I have string which is expected to look like this :

`final old-version=1.2.3-old new-version=1.2.4`

Im trying to extract the version numbers from the string and create two variables `old-version` and `new-version` where :

```
old-version=1.2.3-old
new-version=1.2.4
```

This is what I've come up with :

```
x='final old-version=1.2.3-old new-version=1.2.4'
echo $x | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d'=' -f2
```

Using this I get the value of `old-version`. However this way falls apart quickly if for some reason I get a string like `final new-version=1.2.4 old-version=1.2.3-old`

Is there is better / cleaner / more reliable way of extracting my substrings and their values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the bash shell and P.E. parameter expansion and read

```
x='final old-version=1.2.3-old new-version=1.2.4'
read -r _ old new <<< "$x"; printf '%s\n' "${old#*=}" "${new#*=}"
```

or using array with the `-a` option from read.

```
x='final old-version=1.2.3-old new-version=1.2.4'
read -ra var <<< "$x"; printf '%s\n' "${var[1]#*=}" "${var[2]#*=}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using several steps you can do this entirely with `bash` built-ins

```
x='final old-version=1.2.3-old new-version=1.2.4'

oldnew=${x#* }          # "old-version=1.2.3-old new-version=1.2.4"
old=${oldnew% *}        # "old-version=1.2.3-old"
new=${oldnew#* }        # "new-version=1.2.4"

oldversion=${old#*=}    # "1.2.3-old"
newversion=${new#*=}    # "1.2.4"

echo "Old version is >$oldversion<"
echo "New version is >$newversion<"
```

As two examples of the `#` and `%` operators,

- the `${x#* }` construct removes a string matching the glob `*{space}` off the front of the string `$x`.
- the `${oldnew% *}` construct removes a string matching the glob `{space}*` from the rear of the string

---

Here's another version, this one considerably shorter, using an array to slice the `$x` variable at whitespace

```
x='final old-version=1.2.3-old new-version=1.2.4'

oldnew=($x)                   # array ('final', 'old-version=1.2.3-old', 'new-version=1.2.4')
oldversion=${oldnew[1]#*=}    # "1.2.3-old"
newversion=${oldnew[2]#*=}    # "1.2.4"

echo "Old version is >$oldversion<"
echo "New version is >$newversion<"
```